# Springboot event publisher with delay

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, event-handling

I am using spring events to publish events, but i want my listener to receive published message with a delay (in order to wait for my program to complete some tasks)

is there a way to set a delay to receive my event lately ?

(i made some research but only active mq seem to have the delay option but i dont want to create a real queue, only an event driven pattern in my application and i also dont want to configure spring integration)

Comment: What is your aim to make a delay? If you want your main thread to be waited then first complete your tasks and publish your event after. However, if you need something asynchronous execution you may configure asynchronous event listeners by using Spring's `@Async` and `@EventListener` annotations together.

Comment: @YavuzTas yes iam waiting for a task to complete. but it's a task made by an external component i cannot control it, so i can only delay ma own task to start.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you are coding defensively by delaying events in order to not overwhelm your listener. Try to use reactive programing constructs instead, such as the ones provided by project reactor, they come with built in back pressure which is specifically designed to solve your producer-consumer problem.

Comment: thank you, i already use webflux but didnt know about the delay method, i can now delay my task without event mecanism !